# IQueryable.Count() or IEnumerable.Count() versus Single() throwing exception?

Tags: c#, .net, exception, linq-to-entities, enumeration

We have a repository (Entity Framework) which queries for single records - only a single record should exist for any given query. Initially, our queries were `SingleOrDefault()`.

Clearly, multiple results in the query will throw exception; and none are wrapped by `try/catch`. Rather than wrapping these queries in a `try/catch` block, I proposed an extension method as follows:

```
  public static bool IsEmpty<T>(this IQueryable<T> Query, out int Count) {
     Count = Query.Count();
     return Count == 0;
  }
```

This has advantages in more ways than simply determining if I have an empty query return or single result return.

The alternative is to wrap my query in a try/catch. My question is whether the extension method or expense of catching an exception is preferred. So as not be subjective, I am specifically referring to the cost of catching and throwing an exception versus the cost of the `Count()` method.

Although the database is expected to only return a single record, my approach is that the database will contain unexpected records. I don't perceive this to be an exceptional event, therefore I do not perceive the need for throwing an exception.

The typical implementation of the extension method is as follows:

```
     var query = Repository.All().Where(*/ some criteria */);

     int count;
     if (query.IsEmpty(out count)) {
        // handle empty return
     } else if (count > 1) {
        // handle unexpected returns
     }

     return query.Single();
```

**Edit**
An important note: we want to be informed of ambiguous results and how many records are returned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful not to execute the query multiple times by accident.

```
var query =
    Repository.All()
    .Where(*/ some criteria */)
    .Take(2) //magic here
    .ToList();

if (query.Count == 0) {
    // handle empty return
} else if (query.Count > 1) {
    // handle unexpected returns
}

return query.Single();
```

Query the `TOP 2` rows to handle all cases.

Comment: might want to add a few line breaks to that query to make it easier to read.

Comment: So `Take(2)` does what when only one record is returned? We might want to know how many 'ambiguous' records are returned.

Comment: Also, my understanding is that by adding the `Count()` method actually executes the query as `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ...` as opposed to `SELECT * FROM ...`. A `SELECT COUNT(*)` incurs considerably less overhead than the actual query.

Comment: When only one record is returned you will only receive 1 item.